# How to schedule monitor for sleep mode?

Tags: monitor, schedule

I have presentation in some day of week in university. Some time I need go to the board for describe my notes. So I left my laptop and go to the board.
Some time It's take time to describe what is happening in my note. So my screen is going to black and I need to come back to my laptop to turn screen on.

I can't prevent my screen to turn off because I always forget to turn it off when I was in my office so it turn on for long time.

I'm looking for software that I can give my class schedule and software prevent my screen off  so I can easily describe my notes in class.

Thanks.

Comment: What application you use for presentation?

Comment: Most of the time i Use PDF reader ( Okular )

Comment: You use Okular in KDE or Unity environment?

Comment: I don't use KDE. I use Gnome.